# How to move and overwrite all files from one directory to another?

Tags: java

I know about the Methods in `FileUtils`, but the `FileUtils` won't overwrite.

Also in `Files.move("", "", StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)` when the file exists and it's not empty, then the following exception is thrown: `java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException`

Sample:

```
/file1/test1
/file2/test1
```

How do I merge, move, and overwrite (such as move in windows), `/file1/test1` to `/file2/test1` ?

has java function for this job? I want don't write any method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an operation to move and overwrite files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400030/is-there-an-operation-to-move-and-overwrite-files)

Answer (score 0):

You could do **naive** approach with standard java util functions, and nit with Files.
First, write a method, what will move and overwrite **one** file. Before moving, **check** if the file with this name is is the target folder and **delete** it, what is simpler, (or open end overwrite content, what is unnecessary complicated). 
Then, get the list of all files in source folder and apply the method above in the loop.